# get a response from cassandra binary protocol using node streams

Tags: node.js, stream, binary, cassandra

Trying to learn more about streams and cassandra, so figured I'd try out the binary protocol. I can't even get it to respond though.

```
var net = require('net');
var util = require('util');
var stream = require('stream');

var session;
session = net.connect({ port: 9160 }, function () {
  console.log('connected');

  var header = new Buffer([ 0x01, 0x00, 0x01, 0x01 ]);
  var length = new Buffer(4);
  var body = new Buffer("{'CQL_VERSION':'3.0.0'}", 'utf8');
  length.writeUInt32BE(body.length, 0);

  session.write(header);
  session.write(length);
  session.write(body);

  setTimeout(function () { session.end(); }, 5000);
});

session.on('error', function (err) {
  console.log(err);
});

var client = new (stream.Writable);

client._write = function (chunk, _, next) {
  console.log('response received');
  next();
};

session.pipe(client);
```

The program runs for 5 seconds, printing "connected" almost immediately, but the writable stream never receives content from the database. Any help would be much appreciated!

---

I'm working off of this [documentation for the binary protocol](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=cassandra.git;a=blob_plain;f=doc/native_protocol.spec;hb=refs/heads/cassandra-1.2) and [this guide to node streams](https://github.com/substack/stream-handbook).

Cassandra is running, version `2.0.5`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

9160 is the Thrift's port. Have you tried your code with port 9042?